# Do de Bruijn cycles always exist for each $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know that the answer is yes, and one can prove it by using Euler graphs. But I am not very familiar with graph theory and  I am wondering is there another simple way to prove that $B(k,n)$ for all positive integers $k$ and $n$.

If there is no other way to prove it,there is many proofs using Euler graphs available on the internet but many of them are not easy to read, Does any one know where to find a readable proof of this. Also if someone know a good resource to study De bruijn sequences and it's application , this will be great

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article mentions other ways to construct de Bruijn sequences, including one using Lyndon words, but the Euler circuit method is elegant, and I doubt you'll find a simpler construction.  *Applied Combinatorics* by Roberts and Tesman has a very clear discussion.

Here's the idea: when we have any binary sequence, say
$$0010011010011101011001\ldots,$$
and a specified frame width, say $n=4$, then as the frame is moved from left to right,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\color{red}{0010}011010011101011001\ldots\\
&0\color{red}{0100}11010011101011001\ldots\\
&00\color{red}{1001}1010011101011001\ldots\\
&001\color{red}{0011}010011101011001\ldots\\
&0010\color{red}{0110}10011101011001\ldots,
\end{aligned}
$$
the first $n-1$ digits of any frame match the last $n-1$ digits of the preceding frame.  The same is, of course, true of sequences over larger alphabets.

This gives rise to the following idea: call an $n$-digit sequence $s_2$ **compatible** with an $n$-digit sequence $s_1$ if they could occur in consecutive
frames, that is, if the first $n-1$ digits of $s_2$ match the last $n-1$ digits of $s_1$.

The de Bruijn graph is a visual representation of compatibility: let the vertices be labeled by $n$-digit sequences, and draw an arrow from the vertex labeled $s_1$ to to the vertex labeled $s_2$ if $s_2$ is compatible with $s_1$.  For a binary alphabet, each vertex of the de Bruijn graph would have two outgoing arrows, one labeled by $0$, the other by $1$.  For example, there would be an arrow from the vertex $0010$ to the vertex $0100$ labeled $0$ and an arrow from $0010$ to $0101$ labeled $1$.  For similar reasons, each vertex will have two incoming arrows.  So $0010$ will have an arrow coming from $0001$ and an arrow coming from $1001$.  Both arrows will be labeled $0$.

So any binary sequence corresponds to a particular path on the de Bruijn graph.  If the sequence is to be cyclic, the path must return to its starting point, that is, it must be a circuit.  If the sequence is to be a de Bruijn cycle, than the circuit must include every vertex of the graph, that is, every $n$-digit sequence, exactly once before returning to the starting vertex.  A circuit that does this is called a **Hamiltonian circuit**.

Therefore the problem of deciding the existence of a de Bruijn cycle $B(k,n)$ is equivalent to the problem of deciding the existence of a Hamiltonian circuit on the de Bruijn graph representing the sequences of length $n$ over an alphabet of size $k$.  The Hamiltonian circuit problem is not known to have an efficient general solution.

There's an inspired idea that converts the problem to the generally more tractable **Euler circuit** problem.  (An Euler circuit is one that uses every arrow in the graph exactly once.)  We had labeled arrows of the graph by elements of the alphabet ($0$ and $1$ in the binary case).  Another possible labeling is the following.  Label the arrow joining the vertex $0010$ to $0100$ by the five-digit sequence $00100$.  In general, label the arrow joining vertex $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ to vertex $a_2a_3\ldots a_{n+1}$ by the $(n+1)$-digit sequence $a_1a_2\ldots a_{n+1}$.  Every $(n+1)$-digit sequence over a $k$-letter alphabet labels a unique arrow of the de Bruijn graph whose vertices are the sequences of length $n$.  A check: each of the $k^n$ vertices has $k$ outgoing arrows, giving a total of $k^{n+1}$ arrows in the graph.

If a Hamiltonian circuit uses a given arrow in the graph, then the corresponding $(n+1)$-digit label appears in the sequence.  A Hamiltonian circuit will not use all arrows, however.  In fact, since a Hamiltonian circuit uses each vertex once, it will use one incoming arrow and one outgoing arrow of each vertex.  The other $k-1$ incoming arrows and the other $k-1$ outgoing arrows of a vertex will never be used.

An Euler circuit of the de Bruijn graph, on the other hand, will use every arrow exactly once, and hence will correspond to a de Bruijn cycle $B(k,n+1)$.  Therefore to find a $B(k,n)$ we need to find an Euler circuit of the de Bruijn graph whose vertices represent sequences of length $n-1$.  A basic result is that an Euler circuit in a directed graph exists if and only if the number of incoming arrows at each vertex equals the number of outgoing arrows, assuming a connected graph.  De Bruijn graphs have this property as was shown above.  Hence a $B(k,n)$ exists.

**Notes about graph theory:**  you say you are not very familiar with graph theory, but you don't need to know all that much.  A **graph** is a set of vertices connected by edges.  An **Euler circuit** is a path in the graph that returns to its starting vertex having used each edge in the graph exactly one time.  The main result about Euler circuits is that, assuming all edges lie in the same connected component of the graph, there is an Euler circuit if and only if the number of edges at every vertex is even.  You can think about why this is true, or read up about it.  It's probably a more important piece of mathematics than are de Bruijn sequences anyway.  At any rate, some playing around with graphs that do and don't satisfy the condition should convince you pretty quickly.

One small generalization is needed.  If you put an arrow on each edge of a graph, you have a **directed graph**.  The generalization of Euler's condition to this case is that an Euler circuit exists if and only if the number of incoming edges at each vertex equals the number of outgoing edges.